# Would this question be off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask about statistics on how many imported good and services have tariffs in US. I dont know why but I have the feeling this might be offtopic somehow. Would this question be off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

I think the question is on topic. We have, for example a tag [data-request](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) that could be relevant.